# Set custom publishing page layout custom field programatically

Tags: page-layout, object-model

I have a custom publishing page content type, based on the Publishing Article Page content type. On this content type, I have a custom field named "PageContentCategory". In my code to create new pages, I tried this:

```
PublishingPage newPublishingPage = this.currentPublishingWeb.GetPublishingPages().Add(pageName, newPageSelectedLayout);

if (pageContent.IsEmpty())
{
    pageContent = Properties.Resources.EAWorldArticleHandler_CreateNewArticlePage_DefaultPageContent;
}

newPublishingPage.ListItem[new Guid("{93496B35-7EC3-4132-B0D0-3BDC5606F5EF}")] = pageContentCategory;
newPublishingPage.ListItem[FieldId.PublishingPageContent] = pageContent;
newPublishingPage.Title = pageTitle;
newPublishingPage.Update();
```

I have also tried to set it by the field name:

```
PublishingPage newPublishingPage = this.currentPublishingWeb.GetPublishingPages().Add(pageName, newPageSelectedLayout);

if (pageContent.IsEmpty())
{
    pageContent = Properties.Resources.EAWorldArticleHandler_CreateNewArticlePage_DefaultPageContent;
}

newPublishingPage.ListItem["PageContentCategory"] = pageContentCategory;
newPublishingPage.ListItem[FieldId.PublishingPageContent] = pageContent;
newPublishingPage.Title = pageTitle;
newPublishingPage.Update();
```

Both of these methods throw an error. Is there any way for me to set my custom field's value in code like this?

Comment: What type of field is `PageContentCategory`, and what is the value of `pageContentCategory`?

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution to my problem was that I had to programmatically add the content type to the pages list instead of letting it be added automatically the first time a page with that content type was added. Apparently if you let SharePoint automatically add the content type to the pages list then it somehow doesn't get bound properly. So adding the content type first solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hope this customfiled is already available in the Pages library. If not make sure that the source content type is already added on the Pages library.
2. Try this piece of code

Alfter you add yur page do an update.

```
newPublishingPage.Update();
```

Further update this field of the listitem.

```
newPublishingPage.ListItem["PageContentCategory"] = pageContentCategory;
newPublishingPage.ListItem[FieldId.PublishingPageContent] = pageContent;
newPublishingPage.Title = pageTitle;
newPublishingPage.Update();
```

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work either.